# Where to store data, in flask, while paginating

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, pagination

Respected people:
I need a hint as to where should I hold the data, that I need to paginate, I am using flask.
Should I use session to remember what data I sent earlier, and do the same for subsequent requests?
Also, how should I hold the data sent from the API in json format?

```
data_received_from_the_api = calltoApi()
#How do I make flask to remember/store above data,
#for pagination, If I am not using sessions.
```

I am thinking of maintaining a list, with session[current-index], session[previous-index]. The json data has 5 fields and the number of json-records sent by the API is 100.

Could it be done without using session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a list approach in a project:

When the page is loaded, if the req is a POST it check for previous ones and rememberers the actual:

```
if request.method == "POST" and list(request.form.to_dict().values())[0] in req_indicator_html_names_dict.keys() :
    selector_remember = ast.literal_eval( list(request.form.to_dict().keys())[0] )
else :
    selector_remember = []
```

appending the actual request to the list:

```
selector_remember.append( req_ind_html_name )
```

It then pass the list to the page so you can keep track of the previous requests.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying, Sir: Why you are using `ast.literal_eval()`...You are a Postdoc researcher and I am a Nodoc researcher, hence finding it tough, lol. Although, you have given me a hint.

Comment: it was an old project that came up to my mind when you asked. What do you mean by "why?"

Comment: "What do you mean by "why?" " - I thought that I too need to use it, but I have never heard of it...that's why I asked it, politely.

Comment: It is a command to reconvert python object from string that matches objects format (e.g. https://kite.com/python/docs/ast.literal_eval). For example if you have a string like "{'a' : 1, 'b' :2}" if you pass through ast.literal_eval("{'a' : 1, 'b' :2}") it automatically knows that is a dictionary, same for lists (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html). You are very welcome! Happy to help.

Comment: A question, Sir - Since no session is involved, how would flask remember the request? Is it like default session/cookie is used to identify the request & subsequent requests?

Comment: Yes this uses the session in order to remember the requests. It is pretty simple to implement and very useful (https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/).